# C# equivalent of java Matcher.hitEnd()

Tags: c#, java, regex

Is there an equivalent of `java.util.regex.Matcher.hitEnd()` in C# Regex?

Javadoc for `boolean hitEnd()`:

> Returns true if the end of input was hit by the search engine in the last match operation performed by this matcher. When this method returns true, then it is possible that more input would have changed the result of the last search.
>
> @return  true iff the end of input was hit in the last match; false otherwise

More reference to [hitEnd](https://stackoverflow.com/a/417365)

Comment: Is that not the equivalent of `stuff_here$`?

Comment: what's your understanding on this method

Comment: The [same](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2526756/can-java-util-regex-pattern-do-partial-matches), but in C#

Comment: I guess you have to use PCRE.Net package since the function is from built-in regex parser/compiler and CLR default parser lacks it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Built-in .NET alternative

It seems there is no direct built-in .NET alternative (within the `System.Text.RegularExpressions` namespace) to the Java `java.util.regex.Matcher.hitEnd()` method.

## Alternative libraries

Probably, an alternative library could be found that provides the required alternative.

### PCRE.NET

For example, a quick search revealed the library: [ltrzesniewski/pcre-net: PCRE.NET - Perl Compatible Regular Expressions for .NET](https://github.com/ltrzesniewski/pcre-net). As per its documentation (`README.md`), the library supports the partial matching:

> ## Example usage
>
> <…>
>
> - Partial matching:
>
>   ```
>   var regex = new PcreRegex(@"(?<=abc)123");
>   var match = regex.Match("xyzabc12", PcreMatchOptions.PartialSoft);
>   // result: match.IsPartialMatch == true
>   ```

Comment: And a partial match means the same as hit the end ? Really, what has this to do with is this the end. Obviously, you don't need a library to find this out .

Comment: @sln, quoting [ltrzesniewski/pcre-net: PCRE.NET - Perl Compatible Regular Expressions for .NET](https://github.com/ltrzesniewski/pcre-net): «Partial matching (when the subject is too short to match the pattern)». As I understand, it means that the end of the subject (the input string) has been hit.

Comment: Begin to wonder if you need an  additional library to compare the match position plus length to the target length, you know what I mean ? I mean, there is no magic in Regular Expressions, absolutely none, no elixers, it's all hooey and snaked oil my man !! A bunch of bogosity and bolognies ..

Answer (score 2):

To know if the end has been reached -

I submit that it is as easy as adding `(\z)?` at the end of your regex,
or anyplace in your regex where you think could match to the end.

This is a passive check you can do, and it will not interfere with any of
the other constructs in any way.

Here is a C# sample usage:

```
var str =
    "Foo $var1 <br/>Yes\n" +
    "......... <br/>\n" +
    "......... <br/><br/>\n" +
    "Foo $var2 <br/>Yes\n" +
    "..........<br/>\n" +
    "Yes..........<br/>\n" +
    "..........<br/>\n" +
    "YesYes";

var rx = new Regex(@"Yes(\z)?");

Match M = rx.Match(str);
while (M.Success)
{
    bool bAtEnd = M.Groups[1].Success;
    Console.WriteLine("Match = {0} , At end  {1}", M.ToString(), bAtEnd);
    M = M.NextMatch();
}
```

Output:

```
Match = Yes , At end  False
Match = Yes , At end  False
Match = Yes , At end  False
Match = Yes , At end  False
Match = Yes , At end  True
```

Answer (score 0):

No.

But it is not hard to build it yourself.

If using [`Regex.Match(…)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.match.aspx) (ie. match the expression once) then:

```
bool hitEnd = match.Success && input.Length == (match.Index + match.Length)
```

If using [`Regex.Matches(…)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7sf90t3.aspx) returning a [`MatchCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.matchcollection.aspx) the last successful match is needed (with a little [`Enumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aspx) help) and can easily be an extension method:

```
static bool HitEnd(this MatchCollection matches, string input) {
  if (matches.Count == 0) {
    return false; // No matches at all
  }
  var lastMatch = matches.Cast<Match>().Last();
  return input.Length == (lastMatch.Index + lastMatch.Length)
}
```

Comment: It's not that. You are wrong. Java `hitEnd`, for example, : `regex = "[0-9]abc"; input = "1ab"`. Does not match, but hitEnd is true.

Comment: @Michael If you are interested in this fail case... that's more difficult to work out if it is possible (and that's a big if).